# Number Theory and d-Self-Contained Numbers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, integers

Given any natural number $N = a_{n}a_{n-1}\ldots a_{1}$, let us associate to it the set $S_{N} = \bigcup_{j=1}^{n}\{(a_{j},j)\}$. We're going to define a *d-self-contained* number as any natural number which satisfies the rule:
\begin{align*}
&\forall k\leq n,\exists\sigma\subset S_{N}\setminus\{(a_{k},k)\}; a_{k} = \sum_{s\in\sigma}(-1)^{e_{s}}\|p_{1}(s)\|^{d},\\
&\text{where}\,\,n\geq 3,\,\,e_{s}\in\{0,1\}\,\,\text{and}\,\,\#\sigma\geq 2
\end{align*}
In other words, a number is *d-self-contained* if each of its digits can be obtained from the others as a linear combination of their d-th power (where d is natural and fixed) whose coefficients belong to the set {-1,0,1}, where at least two of these coefficients are non-zero terms. It is worth saying that $p_{1}$ is the projection mapping on the first coordinate. Let us work it through examples.
The number 101 is 2-self-contained since we can rewrite its digits as: $1 = 0^{2} + 1^{2}$ and $0 = 1^{2} - 1^{2}$. Furthermore, the number 101 is d-self-contained for every d. Indeed, we have: 
$$1 = 0 + 1 = 0^{d} + 1^{d}\,\,\text{and}\,\,0 = 1 - 1 = 1^{d} - 1^{d}$$
On the other hand, the number 121 is not 2-self-contained given that:
$$1 \neq 2^{2} - 1^{2}\,\,\text{and}\,\,1\neq 2^{2} + 1^{2}$$
Although it is 1-self-contained. What about the 3-self-contained numbers? Here it comes an example which proves that they exist: 111111112. Undoubtedly, its digits satisfy the following relationships:
$$1 = 2^{3} - 1^{3} - 1^{3} - 1^{3} - 1^{3} - 1^{3} - 1^{3} - 1^{3}\,\,\text{and}\,\,2 = 1^{3} + 1^{3}$$
Even more, this number is also 1,2-self-contained. Really, we have:
$$1 = 2 - 1\,\,\text{and}\,\,2 = 1 + 1;\quad
1 = 2^{2} - 1^{2} - 1^{2} - 1^{2}\,\,\text{and}\,\,2 = 1^{2} + 1^{2}$$
Besides that, this example provides us with a way to build any d-self-contained number:
$$N = \overbrace{11\ldots 1}^{2^{d}}2\Rightarrow 2^{d} = \overbrace{1^{d} + 1^{d} + \ldots + 1^{d}}^{2^{d}}\,\,\text{and}\,\,1 = 2^{d} - \overbrace{1^{d} - 1^{d} - \ldots - 1^{d}}^{2^{d} - 1}$$
Since the definition has been made clear, I would like to make some questions. First of all, does any one can propose any criterion to identify them quickly? In second place, is there any formula which generates them all? And, finally, if we denote the set of d-self-contained numbers by $A_{d}$, does the next proposition hold: $A_{1}\supset A_{2}\supset\ldots\supset A_{k}\supset\ldots$? Thank you in advance for any contribution.

Comment: This might be close to what you're looking for, at least for 3-digit numbers: http://oeis.org/A064544

Comment: @RobertSoupe Thanks for the reference.

Comment: Also posted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/243179/number-theory-characterization-problem without notification of either site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of any easy test, but here is a Python program which can find all self-contained numbers in a given range:

```
mem = dict() #global dictionary for memoization

def expressible(m,digits,k):
    if (m,digits,k) in mem:
        return mem[(m,digits,k)]
    elif m == 0 and k == 0:
        mem[(m,digits,k)] = True
        return True
    elif len(digits) == 0 or k > len(digits):
        mem[(m,digits,k)] = False
        return False
    else:
        for d in set(digits):
            i = int(d)
            remaining = digits.replace(d,'',1)
            if expressible(m + i,remaining, k-1) or expressible(m - i,remaining, k-1):
                mem[(m,digits,k)] = True
                return True
        #if we reach here:
        mem[(m,digits,k)] = False
        return False

def selfContained(a,b):
    nums = []
    for n in range(a,b+1):
        digits = ''.join(sorted(str(n)))
        contained = True #until a counter-example found
        for d in set(digits):
            i = int(d)
            remaining = digits.replace(d,'',1)
            if not expressible(i,remaining,2):
                contained = False
                break
            if not contained: break
        #if we reach here and contained is still true, no counterxamples, so:
        if contained: nums.append(n)
    mem.clear()
    return nums
```

For example,

```
>>> selfContained(1,360)
[101, 110, 112, 121, 123, 132, 134, 143, 145, 154, 156, 165, 167, 176, 178, 187, 189, 198, 202, 211, 213, 220, 224, 231, 235, 242, 246, 253, 257, 264, 268, 275, 279, 286, 297, 303, 312, 314, 321, 325, 330, 336, 341, 347, 352, 358]
```

this list agrees with the 3-digit numbers in the OEIS sequence linked to by @RobertSoupe .

The evaluation

```
nums = selfContained(0,1000000)
```

takes about 3 seconds and returns a list of 322378 numbers, the last 10 of which are

```
999909, 999918, 999927, 999936, 999945, 999954, 999963, 999972, 999981, 999990
```

**On Edit**: I tweaked the code a bit to make it run faster. It can now run out to 10,000,000 in less than a minute. Doing so turns up 4,768,482 self-contained numbers in that range. The percentage is increasing. It is easy to see that the asymptotic density of self-contained numbers is 1. In fact, the proof seems almost trivial: any number in which every digit occurs at least 2 times is self-contained, and the asymptotic density of such numbers is 1. Somewhat interestingly, this proof holds for any base (and not just base 10). Doubtless the *rate* at which the density approaches 1 depends on the base.

**On Further Edit**: Out to 100,000,000 (about 9 minutes for my program) there are 63,750,290 self-contained numbers. I'm not sure if it is feasible to go out to 1 billion with the program on my machine. It would be interesting to write an optimized C version and see how far out it can be taken.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an easy answer to the last question: $10127$ is $3$-self-contained ($7 = 2^3 - 1^3$, $2^3 = 1^3+1^3$, $1^3 = 1^3+0^3$, $0=1^3-1^3$), but it's not $2$-self-contained because $7 > 1^2+0^2+1^2+2^2$.  Similarly I believe $10129$ and $111129$ are in $A_3 \setminus A_2$.  Thus $A_2 \not\supset A_3$, so the infinite descending chain proposition is false.

I suspect that, much like the OEIS sequence that Robert Soupe points to, the structure of $A_d$ for any fixed $d$ is quite simple and can described by a finite automaton.  But I hesitate to make any guesses as to how the complexity grows with $d$.